# Zodiac Calculator 2.7.6 Will not calculate sign, line error date not defined. Need help, noob at programming

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
Year = input("year of birth:" )
Month = input("month of birth:" )
Day = input("day of birth:" )
Date_of_Birth = (str(Day) + "/" + str(Month) + "/" + str(Year))
print('Your Date of Birth is ' + Date_of_Birth)
d = date.today()
y = d.year
age = y - int(Year)
print('Your age is ' + str(age))

if ((int(Month)==12 and int(Day) >= 22)or(int(Month)==1 and int(Day)<= 19)):
        Signo_Zodiacal = ("\n Capricorn")
elif ((int(Month)==1 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==2 and int(Day)<= 17)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n aquarium")
elif ((int(Month)==2 and int(Day) >= 18)or(int(Month)==3 and int(Day)<= 19)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Pices")
elif ((int(Month)==3 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==4 and int(Day)<= 19)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Aries")
elif ((int(Month)==4 and int(Day) >= 20)or(int(Month)==5 and int(Day)<= 20)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Taurus")
elif ((int(Month)==5 and int(Day) >= 21)or(int(Month)==6 and int(Day)<= 20)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Gemini")
elif ((int(Month)==6 and int(Day) >= 21)or(int(Month)==7 and int(Day)<= 22)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Cancer")
elif ((int(Month)==7 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==8 and int(Day)<= 22)): 
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Leo")
elif ((int(Month)==8 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==9 and int(Day)<= 22)): 
            Signo_Zodiacal = ("\n Virgo")
elif ((int(Month)==9 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==10 and int(Day)<= 22)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Libra")
elif ((int(Month)==10 and int(Day) >= 23)or(int(Month)==11 and int(Day)<= 21)): 
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Scorpio")
elif ((int(Month)==11 and int(Day) >= 22)or(int(Month)==12 and int(Day)<= 21)):
            zodiac_sign = ("\n Sagittarius")

print(zodiac_sign)
```

I need some assistance with getting the code to bring up zodiac sign.I'm a noob to coding.Keep getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Python\updatedZodiacSign.py", line 6, in 
    d = date.today()
NameError: name 'date' is not defined

I need some assistance with getting the code to bring up zodiac sign.I'm a noob to coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this at the top

```
from datetime import date
```

Python doesn't know what a date object is until you import it from the datetime module.

Comment: Thank you that worked! Appreciate your help. Like I said I'm new to coding and my teacher just runs through it like everyone should know. Can you dumb it down for me please. I'm in "Introduction to Programming Logic".

Comment: When you call date.today() python thinks pacman wants to call the method today() on the object 'date'.  But by default python doesn't know what a date is.  There's code that defines what the date object does in a module (that's just another python file) called datetime.  Datetime is one of the standard modules that comes with python.  There are a lot of standard modules, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/.  They do all sorts of things that you don't need to worry about.  When you import date from datetime you tell python use the object date from the standard library datetime module.

Comment: There's the documentation for the datetime standard module btw https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Thank you for breaking it down for me.